# Opencv configuration in VS2015: how to remove inherited values

Tags: opencv

I once configured opencv3.1. in vs2015. But now I want to switch to a newer opencv3.2. In doing the configurations, that is, add include and lib directories and additional dependencies, there are inherited values pertaining to opencv3.1. You can see this from the attached screenshot:

[image]

If I keep these inherited values, opencv3.1 will still be called in running projects. Is there any way to get rid of, modify or remove these values to use opencv3.2? What if I uncheck the "Inherit from parent or project defaults"?

Comment: There must be some file stores the old value. Search in your VS Configure directory,  find and modify it.

Comment: @Silencer: can you be more specific about searching? where is the configure directory and what key words to use for searching? Thanks!

Comment: WoBuJiDaoA. I have worked without WinX for two years. So I don't remember the details. Maybe in your `Document/VS2015Project(or so)`.